# DNN Authentication with SignalR

Tags: signalr, dotnetnuke

I'm using a signalR hub to handle server requests from a DNN portal. What is the best way to authenticate a client request from signalr in DNN? Is it possible to do this in a manner similar to the how the DNN implementation of WebAPI uses the services framework or is there another approach?

Comment: Were you successful in getting this working?  I am looking to implement this myself and can't find any information on it.